# disabling ssh session expiration

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I am installed Ubuntu on Virtual Box, and use xshell (a remote terminal application) to ssh to ubuntu. when I hibernate computer during night, after powering it on, the session is expired and I should to ssh to ubuntu again. Is there is way to configure ssh to nut expire during hibernation or after hours of ideal connection? I use Fedora to, if configs have differences please mention it.
I use Windows 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try tmux. On the server side:

```
sudo apt-get install tmux
```

After logging in, start tmux.

```
tmux
```

If the connection breaks, log in again via ssh and reconnect the tmux session. To discover the session number:

```
tmux ls
```

The output might be something like this:

0: 1 windows (created Wed Jan 9 12:27:40 2013)

Connect to the tmux numbered session like this:

```
tmux attach -t 0
```

Then you are right back where you left it.

Comment: Or GNU `screen`. Either don't leave `ssh` connected and instead use some detachable middleware, or use something other than plain `ssh`.

Answer (score 4):

No. `ssh` is a TCP-based protocol with no support for "hibernation" or even for "roaming" (IP address changes). You will need something else if terminating the `ssh` connection before hibernating and connecting again when you resume is not desirable.

Perhaps give `mosh` (["the mobile shell"](http://mosh.mit.edu/)) a try.

But, for short, no. TCP connections are closed on timeout, and `ssh` does not include any strategy to deal with that.

Comment: But ssh has parameters `ConnectionTimeout` and remote terminal apps has `keepalive message interval` parameters. Cannot these parameters be used for this purpose?

Comment: No. That could work to a certain extent, if you are connecting from the same address after resuming, but it always has a time, and you need to have access to both client and server to change the timeout (it's of no use to have a large timeout on your side if the server still has the default value). `keepalive` is to send "keepalive" messages to avoid cases where the connection is dropped due to inactivity. A basic requirement of this is that you must be on and connected to send the keepalive messages... those won't help you *at all* with hibernation.